# How to change the button background image when music is paused

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, html5-audio

I am creating a simple audio player with HTML5 which has only one button. It is autoplay by default but is if the button is pressed it pauses and the other way round. The problem is I would like to to change the background image of the button whenever it is pressed.

Here is my code which obviously does nt change the bg.

```
var beepTwo = $("#musicBeat");
beepTwo[0].play();

$("#dan").click(function() {  
    if (beepTwo[0].paused == false) {
        beepTwo.animate({volume: 0}, 2000, 'swing', function() {
            // really stop the music 
            beepTwo[0].pause();
            $(this).css("background","url (http://goo.gl/w5EWHg)");
        });
     } else {
         beepTwo[0].play();  
         beepTwo.animate({volume: 1}, 2000);
         $(this).css("background","url (http://goo.gl/0GMoZK)");
     }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PE3yw/5/)**

So is how can I change (toggle) the background image according to the button status. It must change by a fade effect.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some simple CSS and take jQuery to add/remove them when necessary. The CSS transition property will give it a fade effect. Adjust the duration (0.5s) to what you want.

Also to note, you had to take `$(this)` outside of the `animate` in the first part of the if clause so it properly references `#dan`

#### JS:

```
$("#dan").click(function() {  
    if (beepTwo[0].paused == false) {
        beepTwo.animate({volume: 0}, 2000, 'swing', function() {
            // really stop the music 
            beepTwo[0].pause();
        });
        $(this).addClass("is-paused");
     } else {
         beepTwo[0].play();  
         beepTwo.animate({volume: 1}, 2000);
         $(this).removeClass("is-paused");
     }

});
```

#### CSS:

```
.button.is-paused {
    background-image:url(http://goo.gl/0GMoZK);
    transition: background 0.5s ease;
}
```

Comment: @daniel Thanks for accepting my answer. If you would also upvote my answer, that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`this` is referring to `beepTwo` when you're changing the background, not `#dan`. Add `var self = this` at the beginning of the click function and change `this` to `self` at the `.css()` function.